# Revert last migration using flyway

Tags: gradle, database-migration, flyway

flyway has a task called `['Undo']`[1](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/gradle/undo) that's supposed to revert last migration.
But the flyway jar `(flyway-core-4.2.0 sources.jar!\org\flywaydb\core\Flyway.java)`doesn't have that method so when I run `gradlew flywayUndo` , I get following error . But when I run `gradlew flywayInfo` it works fine as the `info` method exists in the jar. How to undo last mighration using flyway gradle jar ?

```
Task 'flywayUndo' not found in project ':applications/XXXXXX'. Some candidates are: 'flywayInfo'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`flywayUndo` task is only available in paid versions of Flyway. You can see this [here](https://flywaydb.org/download/). `Undo` is available only for pro and enterprise versions of framework.